# Как прочитать значение элемента iframe, если он появляется динамически?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Внутри **site1** (наш сайт) есть iframe от **site2** (не наш сайт).
Если после загрузки страницы мышкой просмотреть дерево элементов (в инструменте разработчиков), а потом посмотреть значение элемента **iframe**, то значение увидим.
Значение смотрю с помощью этой строчки кода: `document.querySelector("text#textCur").innerHTML`

Но если после перезагрузки страницы сразу посмотреть значение элемента **iframe**, то пишет о том, что такого элемента нет (пока не проделаем действия описанные выше).

Как сделать так, чтобы мы увидели результат?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в данном случае не с динамическим появлением `iframe`.
По умолчанию, в консоли браузера код выполняется в верхнем фрейме, поэтому логично, что не находится элемент, находящийся внутри `iframe`

Сначала нужно получить сам `iframe` и только потом искать уже внутри него. Однако с этим могут возникнуть трудности из-за ограничений доступа, накладываемых браузером.

###### Почему это работает при выборе мышкой?

Есть обратить внимание, в инструментах разработчика показывается `frame`, в котором выполняется код и при выборе элемента мышкой, он может автоматически измениться.

Также его можно поменять вручную.

Например для `Chrome`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Сначала нужно получить сам iframe и только потом искать уже внутри него._ А как получить сперва сам iframe?

Comment: @ИльнурГабдуллин, зависит от твоей разметки. Если у тебя на странице один iframe, можно так `document.querySelector('iframe')`, чтобы получить документ внутри iframe воспользоваться `.contentDocument`, в итоге выйдет примерно так: `document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector("text#textCur").innerHTML`

Comment: document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument выдает null. А сам: document.querySelector('iframe') показывает данные. Что может быть не так?

Comment: @ИльнурГабдуллин, _Что может быть не так_ - что угодно, скорее всего, как и было указано в ответе, браузер просто запрещает доступ к данным внутри iframe. Конкретнее без твоей разметки сказать нельзя